# Compiling dynamically generated buttons in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to dynamically generate a button in Angular. On click, that button needs to call the `deleteRow()` function and pass in a username. The applicable username is successfully passed to the controller and the resulting button code appears to be properly generated. However, they button ends up passing `undefined` to the `deleteRow()` function. Is this a problem with how I'm using `$compile`?

```
validationApp.controller('usersController', function ($scope, $compile, $http, $timeout){
    $(document).on("click", ".open-confirm-dialog", function () {
        var username = $(this).data('id');
        var btnHtml = '<button class="btn btn-danger" data-title="Delete" ng-click="deleteRow(' + username + ')">DELETE</button>';
        var temp = $compile(btnHtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('deleteButton-dynamic')).append(temp);
    });

    $scope.deleteRow = function(username){
        alert(username); //This shows 'undefined' in the pop-up
        var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "scripts/delete.php",
        data: { un: username },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

    request.success(function() { });
    location.reload();
};
```

HTML as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="usersController">
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
    <table id="users" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th ng-click="sort_by('username');">Username:&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
            <th ng-click="sort_by('submitted_info');">Submitted Info.:&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | orderBy : predicate :reverse)">
                <td>{{data.username}}</td>
                <td>{{data.submitted_info}}</td>
                <td><a href="#confirmModal" class="open-confirm-dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-id='{{data.username}}'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>No customers found</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
        <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Confirm Modal -->
        <div id="confirmModal" user-id="" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete this user from the database?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>     
                <span id="deleteButton-dynamic"></span>
                <!--Working HardCoded Button
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-title="Delete" ng-click="deleteRow('user1')">WorkingButton</button>
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one test is to debug 'this' at the line of your alert and confirm what object is calling the method...you may be able to skip passing the parameter at all and set the button's id to something easily parsed at that point...or a custom attribute

Comment: can you put the html as well?

Comment: Added the HTML for your review as well.

Comment: In "deleteRow(' + username + ')" ... if you add double quotes to wrap username, does it make difference? eg deleteRow(\" ' + username + ....

Comment: Yep, that's what's missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular assumes the value passed to deleteRow is part of the expression, therefore it checks the scope for a key that matches the value of username.  Change the ng-click expression by wrapping the concatenated username string in quotes.  E. G.  deleteRow(\''+ username + '\')

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

To do this you would need to do the following based on the code you gave:

1. define the directive javascript itself

// First define the directive controller

```
function dynamicButton ($scope, $http){
    $scope.deleteRow = function(){
        // here $scope.username is defined based on the value from the parent controller
    };
});
```

// This registers the directive with angular

```
validationApp.directive(dynamicButton.name, function(){
  return {
    controller: dynamicButton.name,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'pathtoyourhtmlpartial',
    scope: {
      username: '='
    }
  }
}
```

2. Update the html, i.e. call the directive from the original controller and save the new partial for the button.

3. trigger the directive in your original controller. (e.g. $scope.buttonSwitchedOn), when that it true, angular will automatically load in and run your directive